# JSON format is giving error when trying to give JSON string inside JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, json.net, postman

I want to create a JSON data in this format where I want to give a JSON string in the value element , but it is giving error that there is something wrong in JSON format. What is the mistake I am making

```
{
  "metafield": {
  "namespace": "inventory",
  "key": "test",
  "value": "[{"5":10,"8":10}]",
  "value_type": "string"
 }
}
```

Comment: You are creating the JSON wrong. `JSON.stringify()` is the *only* way to create JSON. You seem do to something else, like `stringValue1 + stringValue2`. Don't do that. That being said, you don't want a JSON string inside a JSON string. That's silly. Even if you fix this immediate problem the result would still be useless, so I recommend that you re-think your approach.

Comment: You can check your json is valid or not using [this link](http://json.parser.online.fr/) where you can find what's going wrong

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the `"` ,here is how you may write it

```html
{
  "metafield": {
  "namespace": "inventory",
  "key": "test",
  "value": "[{\"5\":10,\"8\":10}]",
  "value_type": "string"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you passed in value as array or object in JSON string no need to `"` like  `"[{'5':10,'8':10}]"` just passed array object value like this `[{"5":10,"8":10}]`

Completely working this string

```
{ 
  "metafield": 
  { 
    "namespace": "inventory",
    "key": "test",
    "value": [{"5":10,"8":10}],
    "valuetype": "string" 
  }
}
```

> If you write `"[{'5':10,'8':10}]"` it consider as a simple string.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes for the attributes of the objects in your array:

```
{  
   "metafield":{  
      "namespace":"inventory",
      "key":"test",
      "value":"[{'5':10,'8':10}]",
      "value_type":"string"
   }
}
```

You can recheck the validity of your JSON here: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com. This service will give you more details of your ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

you can either use `'` or `\"` for this format like `'string'` or `\"string\"`

I don't know you requirement but might be you are doing something wrong with array, may be you need JSON in below format

```
{
    "metafield": {
        "namespace": "inventory",
        "key": "test",
        "value": [{
            "5": 10,
            "8": 10
        }],
        "value_type": "string"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You json format is incorrect.
use this:

```
{
    "metafield": {
        "namespace": "inventory",
        "key": "test",
        "value": [{
            "5": 10
        }, {
            "8": 10
        }],
        "value_type": "string"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "metafield": {
    "namespace": "inventory",
    "key": "test",
    "value": "[{"5":10,"8":10}]",
    "value_type": "string"
  }
}
```

As above `"value": "[{"5":10,"8":10}]",`, If you want to pass `"value"` key value as `array` than this way is wrong to make json string. If you want to pass `"value"` key value as `array` than that key value as `"value": [{"5":10,"8":10}],` for this reason you got invalid json sting error.

I hope this will helps.